# From positive semi-definiteness to positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

One of my lectures includes the following quote from my professor (on a part of a chapter about compatible systems):

> $A^TA$ is semi-positive-definite. If columns of $A$ are linear independent, then $A^TA$ is positive definite and invertible and has only one solution.

I'm fine with the first part of it that it's positive semi-definite since

$\forall x(\neq 0): X^T(A^TA)X=\big\|AX\big\|_2^2 \geq0$

I don't get how from its columns being linearly independent we get to it's being PD.

Comment: You mean that $||AX||_2^2 \geq 0$, not $>0$.

Comment: @ijkilchenko: No, I mean what I've written above. It's from the definition of positive semi-definiteness.

Comment: I presume you mean "$A^T A$ is positive-definite and invertible?"

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić: You're right, thank you.

Comment: @Gigili, "semi" means that it could be equal to 0. Positive-semi-definite is also known as nonnegative-definite. Are you still sure about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Positive-semidefinite

Comment: There is a geometrical interpretation of this. The determinant of $A^TA$ equals the squared volume of the parallelogram spanned by the columns of $A$. This is nonzero exactly when those columns are linearly independent, for rather intuitive geometrical reasons. In this case the system $A^TAx=y$ has one and only one solution by Cramer's rule.

Comment: @ijkilchenko: Ah right, I always mix them up. OK, thanks.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, you should consider making that an actual answer because neither of the answers right now actually answer what OP was asking (there was an edit to the question).

Answer (score 2):

Exactly from the line you have written.
Observe that if the columns of $A$ are ${\bf a}_1,\dots,{\bf a}_n$ then with ${\bf x}=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n }$ we have 
$$A{\bf x}=x_1{\bf a}_1+x_2{\bf a}_2+\dots+x_n{\bf a}_n\,.$$
So, if ${\bf a}_i$'s are linearly independent, that means that $A{\bf x}=0\implies {\bf x}=0$.

Comment: Could you check my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a counterexample to your professor's claim.
Let A= $
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$; clearly, $A$ is linearly independent. And let $x^T=(1 \;\; 2)$.
$$x^T A x=$$
$$\left(1 \;\; 2\right)\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)\left(
\begin{matrix}
1\\
2\\
\end{matrix}
\right)=$$
$$\left(1 \;\; 2\right)\left(
\begin{matrix}
2\\
-1\\
\end{matrix}
\right)=0.$$
Where am I wrong here?

Comment: OP changed the question. This doesn't answer the question anymore.

Comment: It is about $x^T{\bf A}^TAx$ not $x^TAx$.